# Make SKSpriteNode running an action collide with edge of screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skaction

I have an SKSpriteNode which is controlled by the accelerometer to move left and right like so:

```
var destX = myNode.position.x

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {

        let currentX = self.myNode.position.x

        if data.acceleration.x < 0 {
            self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.acceleration.x * 2000)
        } else if data.acceleration.x > 0 {
            self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.acceleration.x * 2000)
        }
        else if data.acceleration.x == 0 {
            self.destX = currentX
        }
    }
}
```

Then, also in the update method, I create an `SKAction` to move the SpriteNode to `destX`:

```
if alive {

        let action = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 1)
        self.myNode.runAction(action)

    }
```

The right - left movement works fine. What I need to do now, though is to make the node so that it can't leave the screen. I tried putting a physics body around the edge of the screen:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height))
self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ScreenEdge

myNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ScreenEdge
```

I have the physics bodies themselves running fine, but the reason the collision is not working between the sprite node and the edge of the screen is that the node is running an action, and actions kind of 'override' physics. Is there any way to make the the node stop at the edge of the screen while still keeping the acceleration from the accelerometer's data? I know that currently, `destX` is a very high or low number, but that is to cause the sprite node to move side to side quickly.

**Basically, I need a way to either a) allow collisions even with an `SKAction` running on the node, or b) make the `moveToX` action stop when the sprite node gets off the screen, and make it start again once the node is back on the screen.**

Thanks!

Comment: I can Recommend to use a collision detection mechanism to achieve this
Make a physics perimeter of the bounds of the screen, and check whether the body(you node) collides with the bounds -> on collide do your action.
Here is a docs and helpful info https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW1

Comment: @NoahCovey One thing to consider...Using SKAction inside update loop might be an overkill. Update loop is running 60 times per second. What you want to do most of the times inside that method is to update node's position property (or velocity property) rather than a create SKAction object every time. After all, it doesn't make sense to run an action with a duration of 1 second inside a method which is executed 60 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:
<sub>(sorry for the Objective C, I am not a swift programmer but will still try to explain how you could do this in your own language)</sub>

```
-(BOOL)isNode:(*SKnode)theNode outOfScene:(*SKScene)theScene
{
BOOL isIt = NO;
if (theNode.position.x > theScene.frame.size.width + (theNode.frame.size.width / 2)){isIt = YES;}
if (theNode.position.x < -(theNode.frame.size.width / 2)){isIt = YES;}
if (theNode.position.y > theScene.frame.size.height + (theNode.frame.size.height / 2)){isIt = YES;}
if (theNode.position.y < -(theNode.frame.size.height / 2)){isIt = YES;}
return isIt;
}
```

Here is how it works

`-(BOOL)isNode:(*SKnode)theNode outOfScene:(*SKScene)theScene` new funtion,
 input variables are: `theNode` a node, and `theScene` the scene to see if it is in in the bounds of.
`BOOL isIt = NO;` creates a new Boolean variable, it's default value is `NO`

```
if (theNode.position.x > theScene.frame.size.width){isIt = YES;}
if (theNode.position.x < 0){isIt = YES;}
if (theNode.position.y > theScene.frame.size.height){isIt = YES;}
if (theNode.position.y < 0){isIt = YES;}
```

check to see if `theNode` is not within `theScene`'s visible bounds.
Sets isIt to Yes if it is out of `theScene`'s bounds.
This assumes that `theNode`'s orientation is (0,0)  <sub>-if you do not know what this means than you should probably ignore it.</sub>

`return isIt` return `isIt` to the sender (thing who 'called' the function)


That is how it is.

#### Note: This code has not been tested, please leave a comment if it is faulty.

### Edit: if `theNode` is not a child of `theScene` you may have to convert the position of `theNode`'s coordinate space to that of `theScene`.

Comment: You are checking Position X/Y I think by default the position is in the middle of the theNode , so the theNode have to be half away from the screen to trigger this function to return YES --Just a Note
+1 for the detailed explanations